# Trying to execute a binary with shelll_exec

Tags: php, bash

It's maybe more a bash oriented question, but it deals with security.

So I'm trying to download a binary (**nc**) from a remote machine that I can access using Php (and *shell_exec* function), I looked for **wget** and found it in **/usr/ports/ftp/** repository, with the following rights:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   512 Dec 27  2013 wget
```

So, as you can see everybody should be abble to execute this. So, I did the following with shell_exec:

```
<?php $output = shell_exec("/usr/ports/ftp/wget"); echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?>
```

But when I executed this script via the server nothing append, which is strange because **shell_exec(ls");** works (it can see the stdout of it) and "**ls**" binary which is in **/bin** as exaclty the same rights

Any suggestion ?

p.s: all of this happens in a training lab of course

Comment: you are just using wget, put an IP address or domain after and see if there is any output, such as: wget bbc.com

Comment: wget with no parameters shows the help, which is likely on STDERR not STDOUT - pass a parameter.

Comment: No when I'm using wget alone on my linux machine I get "wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options"

Comment: @crovers You're right crovers, how would I pass stderr to $output so ?

Comment: look at what crovers just wrote, he explains why you don't see the error.

Comment: I just tried this: <?php $output = shell_exec("/usr/ports/ftp/wget"); echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?> but still no result (and my apache is running)

Comment: append 2>&1 to the command (redirects stream 2 (STDERR) to stream 1 (STDOUT))

Comment: @crovers Thanks! I see something => "/usr/ports/ftp/wget: Permission denied", but why is it denied ?

Comment: I don't understand why it is denied as every body can execute it...

Comment: Ok, my bad "wget" is a directory...

Comment: This is not a "hacking question" post to stack overflow.

Comment: This can be pretty **dangerous** if you pass **untrusted input** to the command.... Why are you not trying with CURL or any php native method to do a http request?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a BSD machine - /usr/ports/ftp/wget is a directory (see the d in the modes of the `ls` output). `wget` is not actually installed on that machine, I suspect, and you're trying to execute a directory.

Try `fetch` (/usr/bin/fetch) instead.